# SharePoint - Use JavaScript to get the list items after filter is applied

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, filter, field, listitem

Consider I have a list called "test"
And it has 5 list items (say a, b, c, d, e)
Now that I apply filter manually on the list items for a particular field
Now the result is 3 list Items.

Now I want to read the fields of these 3 list items through JavaScript & do calculation on it.

I need to access the fields of the currently displayed (after filter is applied manually)

I do not want to filter it in Javascript. But I want to filter some field manually & then I want to read the displayed result. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery will get all the values for a column for the rows that are displayed. It works on SharePoint 2010. I left the code very verbose and with debugging statements so it's easier to understand. Keep in mind that this code will not run in IE with the console closed unless you remove the `console.log` and `debugger` lines.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var columnHeading = "Title";
    var anchor = $("a").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === columnHeading; //find the link that matches the text in the columnHeading variable
    });
    var th = anchor.closest("th"); //Get the parent table header
    var columnIndex = th.index(); //Get the index of the table header in the row for use on other rows
    var table = th.closest("table");
    var i;
    debugger;
    table.find("tbody").first().find("tr").not(":first").each(function() { //Loop over every row in the table EXCEPT the first row because its the table header
        i = $(this).find("td").eq(columnIndex); //find the td element at the index we determined earlier
        console.log($(i).text()); //get the text in the td. You may need to parseInt before any mathematical formulas.
    });
});
```

If you need clarification on anything, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. !! Now I want to read all the td elements at the index. How can it be done ? Meaning, I want to read all the field values for the displayed list items.

Comment: Will you please clarify what you would like to do? Are you asking how to read all values in a row or all values in a column? My example shows how to read all values in a column (the .each loop is iterating through all rows and reading the values from the column).

Comment: Yes, it is reading the column values, for each row I have 5 fields.
For Each row I want to read each fields value and store it in an array. As of now I got it using $(i).next().next(). but it takes so much time to iterate. Need efficient logic. Thanks in advance